# Jinja templates, how to do an import of all macros to follow the DRY principle?

Tags: macros, jinja2

currently I have in many places:

```
{% from "macros/render_product_materials.html" import render_product_materials %}
{% from "macros/render_citation.html" import render_citation %}
{% from "macros/render_product_packages.html" import render_product_packages %}
{% from "macros/render_icon_explanation_section.html" import render_icon_explanation_section %}
{% from "macros/render_percentage_items.html" import render_percentage_items %}
```

this list goes on!

then i call the code in the template:

```
{{render_percentage_items('some args',2,34,55)}}
```

If I change a function name, I have to change it everywhere, if I add a new function, I have to go and import it each time everywhere

I rather just want to do this, something like this:

`{% include 'macros/all_macros.html' %}`

then I just put all imports into `all_macros.html`

But: the imports do not get available in the context

e.g.

```
{% include 'macros/all_macros.html' %}

{{render_percentage_items('some args',2,34,55)}}
```

doesn't work. `render_percentage_items` not found. Now what is the way to do this the jinja way?

Comment: I am not sure but you can try - {% import 'macros/all_macros.html'  as all_macro with context %} then try {{all_macro.render_percentage_items('some args',2,34,55)}}

Comment: this will work when doing a ` {% set .. %}` of the macros inside e.g.  `{% set render_percentage_items = render_percentage_items %} `

Answer (score 0):

Collecting related macros into a single file is a start. Then use `import … as` rather than `include`.

```html
{% import 'macros/all_macros.html' as m %}
{{ m.render_percentage_items('some args', 2, 34, 55) }}
```

So, basically, exactly what SumanKalyan already said.

In many (most?) cases, you won't even need the `with context`, but you can refer [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#import-visibility) to decide if maybe you do. As mentioned in the documentaiton, `with context` disables caching, and usually `import`ed templates only contain macros anyway, which can and should be cached.

[Reference](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#import).