# Jinja2 allowing macros to be extended, but providing a fallback implementation

Tags: python, jinja2

In a project that I'm working on I'd like to be able to declare some common macros which can conveniently be extended by a theme based on Jinja templates.

Here is a representative example of the way I have themes setup and structured:

```
$ tree
.
├── base
│   ├── common_macros.j2
│   └── example.j2
├── example.py
└── theme1
    └── common_macros.j2
```

With `example.py` looking like:

```
from pathlib import Path
import jinja2


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tmplt_root = Path(__file__).parent

    # Setup the base loader to be able to use both "example.j2" and "base/example.j2",
    # thereby allowing themes to implement "example.j2" by extending "base/example.j2".
    base_template_paths = [str(tmplt_root), str(tmplt_root / 'base')]

    env1 = jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(base_template_paths),
    )

    env_themed = jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(['theme1/'] + base_template_paths),
    )

    print('BASE')
    print('----------')
    print(env1.get_template('example.j2').render())

    print('Theme 1')
    print('----------')
    print(env_themed.get_template('example.j2').render())
```

`base/example.j2`:

```
{% from "common_macros.j2" import macro1 %}

{% block main -%}
    {{ macro1() }}
{%- endblock main %}
```

`base/common_macros.j2`:

```
{% macro macro1() -%}
Macro 1 base
{% endmacro %}
```

With this setup I'm able to implement an overriden macro in `theme1/common_macros.j2` (and can even call the base implementation!):

```
{% import "base/common_macros.j2" as base %}

{% macro macro1() -%}
    Theme macro 1!
    {{ base.macro1() }}
{% endmacro %}
```

So far, so good!

```
$ python example.py
BASE
----------


Macro 1 base

Theme 1
----------


Theme macro 1!
    Macro 1 base
```

The problem comes when I add another macro to `base/common_macros.j2` (and use it in `example.j2`) at which point the following error occurs:

```
$ python example.py
BASE
----------


Macro 1 base

    Macro 2 base

Theme 1
----------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 25, in <module>
    print(env_themed.get_template('example.j2').render())
  File "jinja2/environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "jinja2/environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "jinja2/_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "base/example.j2", line 3, in top-level template code
    {% block main -%}
  File "base/example.j2", line 5, in block "main"
    {{ macro2() }}
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: the template 'common_macros.j2' (imported on line 1 in 'example.j2') does not export the requested name 'macro2'
```

Clearly this is caused by the `theme1/common_macros.j2` override not implementing all of the macros that are in the base.

**My question:** What can I do to make this work without needing to redefine *all* of the macros from `base/common_macros.j2` in the `theme1/common_macros.j2`?

Approaches that I've tried and failed with so far:

1. Import all macros from `base/common_macros.j2` into `theme1/common_macros.j2` (equivalent of `from base import *` in Python - remember, I don't want to write down all the macro names that exist in base in each theme, otherwise upgrades would get tedious!).

   Unfortunately this doesn't exist ([Jinja templates, how to do an import of all macros to follow the DRY principle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45249465/jinja-templates-how-to-do-an-import-of-all-macros-to-follow-the-dry-principle))
2. Include the base macros with `{% include "base/common_macros.j2" %}` in the theme (akin to `extends` for non-macro templates).

   Unfortunately only variables exposed explicitly in `theme1/common_macros.j2` are visible (as per https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#import)

I'm more than happy to hear alternative ideas about how to do theming with Jinja if it leads to a solution to the problem and doesn't increase the complexity.

Comment: Have you ever found an answer for this question?